# Error on activating a Journey on MarketCloud - Salesforce Data Entry

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, trigger, journeybuilder, integration

We're trying to activate a journey on marketingcloud with an entry event from salesforce, however, we get the following error:

> FLOW_EXCEPTION;SalesforceObj8c8104b4ca8f6f02648e1286e9460d12_FireJBTrigger (Ação do Apex (legada)) - Não é possível localizar a descrição do Apex para a classe 'et4ae5__JBFireEventV2'. Ela pode ter sido excluída ou alterada.;;Flow Save failed. Unable to activate the Journey, the Sales Cloud user may not have correct permissions. Activating a Journey requires the Run Flow and Manage Force.com Flow permissions.

The validations ran without any errors and the user has all permissions needed to run and manage flows, someone has any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Open a support case

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation of the package solve the problem.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_install_marketing_cloud_connect.htm